# Print sent php curl request

Tags: php, curl

How can I print request I have sent, header and body? Following:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

gives me just $r['request_headers']?

Comment: No sure what you are asking for, but here is the post which will give you complete idea on how `CURL` works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code

Answer (score 1):

i made a server & website specifically for this purpose, http://dumpinput.ratma.net for the website, and https://github.com/divinity76/dumpinput.ratma.net for the server, note that it does not support httpS, so if the input is sensitive, you should probably run your own instance of the server (it's free & open source~), also note that i run the server on a dev-vm from cloudatcost.com, which has a bad reputation for uptime, so don't depend on the website being up.

you could also set up a netcat server as the target of the curl request (but that won't work with `Expect 100 Continue` POST-requests, but the dumpinput server will still work.)

Comment: I solved my problem differently. But upvote for trying to help!